# Ajax sourced jquery dataTable does not work?

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables, jersey-2.0

While i am trying to get data to data Table from MySql table via ajax. It does not render table .

`HTML :-`

```
<table id="view-site-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>site Id</th>
            <th>site Name</th>
            <th>user Name</th>
            <th>channel Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

`Ajax :-`

```
var rule_id = $(this).children('td.slNo').text();
$.ajax({
    url: '/idns/site/getSitesByRuleId/' + rule_id,
    method: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        $("#all-rules-summary-table").hide();
        $('#view-site-table').show();
        $('#view-site-table').DataTable({
            data: data,
            columns: [{
                data: 'siteId'
            }, {
                data: 'siteName'
            }, {
                data: 'userName'
            }, {
                data: 'channelName'
            }, ]
        });
    }
});
```

`Java Resource :-`

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/getSitesByRuleId/{ruleId}")
public List<SitesTO> getSitesByRuleId(@PathParam("ruleId") int ruleId) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException, SQLException{
    List<SitesTO>sites=new ArrayList<SitesTO>();
    try {
        connection =JDBCConnectionUtil.getConnection();
        IdnsSiteDAO sitesByRuleId=new IdnsSiteDAO(connection);
        sites= sitesByRuleId.getSitesByRuleId(ruleId);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error occurs , While trying to getSitesByRuleId.",e); 
        throw new SQLException("Error occurs , While trying to getSitesByRuleId.");
    }
    finally{
        connection.close();
    }

    return sites;
}
```

Kindly some one help me to resolve this.And i want also want to edit table rows and send to server.

Comment: if you try to console.log the data in success does it output the data?

Comment: yes @Mr. Pekka 1 ,i get data at console .but it does not render table

Comment: i assume youre not getting any error?

Comment: no i am not getting any error.console out put :[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
0: Object
channelName: "ch1"
ruleId: 0
siteId: 37
siteName: "www.s1.com"
userName: "user1"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
channelName: "ch2"
ruleId: 0
siteId: 38
siteName: "www.s1.com"
userName: "user2"
__proto__: Object
2: Object
channelName: "ch3"
ruleId: 0
siteId: 39
siteName: "www.s1.com"
userName: "default"
__proto__: Object
3: Object
channelName: "ch1"
ruleId: 0
siteId: 40
siteName: "www.s4.com"
userName: "user2"
__proto__: Object
4: Object
length: 5
__proto__: Array[0]

Comment: @Mr. Pekka table also does not render .

Comment: Created a JSFiddle with your data http://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/Lap4brgn/ is there anything there that isn't in your code?

Comment: @ Mr. annoyingmouse  datatable now works correctly .Now i want to add edit and delete button to each row.how do i do that is there any option in jquery datatable.When i click delete one ajax need to fire and delete appropriate data from server.